# addOnItemTouchListener in recyclerview getting queued

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am showing json data in recyclerview. when i click any item of the recyclerview it should showing some new data. its working fine but the problem is, when i click its getting queued, like if i click tow item one after another, recyclerview will show items for twice.how to solve this issue?

i have tried by setting addOnItemTouchListener null after completion the click, but its showing null pointer exception on next click.

my click listener class below:

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {

    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    private ClickListener clickListener;

    public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

                if (child != null && clickListener != null) {

                    clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {

        View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());

        if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {

            clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));

        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

    }

    public interface ClickListener {

        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use recycle view click listener below is the class and you can esaily use it.

```
public class RecyclerOnClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

    public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerOnClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept){}
```

}

In Activity also you can use it like this

```
recyclerview_productList.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerOnClickListener(AgentCustomerActivity.this, recyclerview_productList, new RecyclerOnClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(AgentCustomerActivity.this, AgentCutomerOrderDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("agent_cutomerId", list.get(position).getCustomerId());
                    intent.putExtra("agent_cutomerName", list.get(position).getCustomerName());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {

                }
            }));
```

Comment: but i not going other intent so how could i implement this?? i have to stay the same intent and update the listview only :(

Comment: you can do it whatever you want, when you click and you get desire data at the position of the list, It is my example, in onItemClick you get the position of list and get the Model object and add it to the list if list having the same model class

Comment: ma'am may be i couldnt clear the ques properly. i am getting the position correctly.

Comment: this is your listener, Can you explain it what do you want when you click recycle view

Comment: onitemclick i am sending req to server and then showing response. but if i click more than once then the list concatenating for that much times.

Comment: It is not big deal when you add data for first time, Clear list before adding data from the server, it will not concatenate again.

Comment: i have tried with that but did not solved because click event queued. like if i clicked 2/3/4 times then concatenate the list for 2/3/4 times :(

Comment: post your activty